# XPath query using contains function

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying an xpath query in the following xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<diccionarios>
  <diccionario>
    <nombre>Diccionario de la Real Academia Española</nombre>
    <siglas>DRAE</siglas>
    <definicion>
      <palabra>ordenador, ra</palabra>
      <punto>Que ordena.</punto>
      <punto>Jefe de una ordenación de pagos u oficina de cuenta y razón.</punto>
      <punto>Máquina electrónica ...</punto>
    </definicion>
    <definicion>
      <palabra>monitor, ra.</palabra>
      <punto>Persona que guía el aprendizaje deportivo, cultural, etc.</punto>
      <punto>Hombre que amonesta o avisa.</punto>
      <punto>Aparato receptor ...</punto>
    </definicion>
  </diccionario>
</diccionarios>
```

I need to get `palabras` tags containing the string `'...'` in `punto` tags. 
I tried

```
//definicion[contains(punto,'...')]/palabra
```

but iI think it only checks the first occurrence of the `punto` tag. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into what contains() takes as arguments. You are passing an element, but it's expecting string. Also some issues with predicates. Here's what you want:

```
//definicion[punto/text()[contains(.,'...')]]/palabra
```

Comment: In particular, when converting a node-set to a string: [“A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order”](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions) which explains why the original version is only checking the first `punto` tag.

Comment: Also, I don’t think you need the `/text()`, `punto[contains(.,'...')` works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this way :

```
//definicion[punto[contains(.,'...')]]/palabra
```

Output :

```
Element='<palabra>ordenador, ra</palabra>'
Element='<palabra>monitor, ra.</palabra>'
```